# Is HornetQ included in jboss-esb-server by default or do I need to explicitly install it?

Tags: jboss, jms, esb, hornetq

I am trying to use the HornetQ JMS provider in place of the legacy JMS provider in my JBoss ESB project, but it's not working.

I successfully went through and ran the example code from the JBoss-ESB tutorial at http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-esb/78-jboss-esb.html - but, in this tutorial, the JBM JMS provider is used. I need to use HornetQ JMS provider instead.

I don't know how to get HornetQ as my JMS provider. Is HornetQ available in jbossesb-server-4.10 by default or do I need to explicitly install it?

Answer (score 0):

The [HornetQ documentation says](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/quickstart-guide/en/html/installation.html#installation.jboss.as4):

> HornetQ can also be deployed in JBoss AS 5. It is not currently shipped by default with the application server (it is scheduled to be shipped as default JMS provider in JBoss Application Server 6.0), so you will need to create new AS 5 profiles to run AS 5 with HornetQ. ... As in AS 4, it is not shipped by default with the application server, so you will need to create new AS 4 profiles to run AS 4 with HornetQ.

So HornetQ is either available as part of JBoss Application Server 6+, or as a standalone server that you can point an AS to. To get HornetQ as your JMS, you're going to need to be running your JBoss ESB install on top of JBoss AS 6 or higher, or to install HornetQ as a standalone server.

So it looks like the answer to your question is "no, it's not part of JBoss ESB, you need to explicitly install it."

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Last question: Can we install hornetq in jboss-esb-server in a similar way as in Jboss AS

Comment: You need JBoss AS or another AS installed in order to have JBoss ESB installed. You should install HornetQ at the AS level, not at the ESB level. HornetQ works at the AS level.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware HornetQ comes in two flavors:

- Embedded in JBoss AS 6.
- As a standalone server.

So in your case I think you need to install either JBoss (with HornetQ) or only HornetQ if you don't need JBoss.